# Genesis 1:26 and 28 tells mankind to "subdue" the earth and "rule over" various animals. Exactly what is meant by this in relation to large animals?

Tags: genesis, authorial-intent

In Genesis 1, up until this command, the conflict in the narrative has been very muted. Sure the chaos waters were there, but God is portrayed as being unthreatened by it, and it soon becomes a mere building material, easily shaped just by speaking. By the time dry land and plants appear, the picture is of a safe and comfortable place for humans to live.

The only mention of any threat to humans are the great sea creatures, the livestock and wild animals all of which are singled out from among the all the other moving creatures presumably because of their size -- being megafauna whose size make them rivals for humans.

But even then, they are portrayed as vegetarian.

So, my question is this: how are we supposed to picture the "ruling" and "subduing"? Are we supposed to guide them to ensure they fill the earth? Do we domesticate them? Do we destroy them to make a safe world? Or is it all a foreshadowing a time later in the narrative when we will be in conflict with animals? Is it really about subduing our carnal desires or subduing spiritual entities?

Answer (score 1):

Given what little is said about animals in the creation account of Genesis, we can only go by what is there. We need to stick to the verses you ask about.

After assigning Adam to perform horticulture in the garden (Genesis 2:15), Adam was tasked with naming the animals. God brought to Adam the animals he had (God-given) authority to name. Naming a living creature shows authority over it. Parents who name their babies do so by parental authority. No baby ever names itself! Intelligence, a grasp of language and the meaning of words are all involved in naming anything, and show a responsibility over, and a superiority over the thing named. And only certain people are entitled to name particular things. For example, unless an inventor or builder of a thing or a structure assigns naming it to another, he or she would be expected to name it. In the garden, God had created both man and all the living creatures and plants, then he authorised Adam to name the animals he brought to him.

Perhaps the key to the answer you seek lies in which animals God had come before Adam. We are only told that :

> "Adam gave names to all cattle, and to the fowl of the air, and to
> every beast of the field" (Genesis 2:20 KJV)

Just to mention that the idea of a 'field' might only have arisen in later generations, after Adam and Eve had been cast out of the garden, to till the earth. Also, there is no mention of Adam naming any sea creatures, whereas the birds *are* mentioned. We have no clue as to the size of any of the creatures Adam named.

Yes, he was to subdue the earth, and to "have dominion over every creeping thing that creeps upon the earth". Since that mandate was given, many creatures have become extinct, so we just do not know exactly what all those creatures were. Also, given that no humans had begun to cross-breed creatures, there would only be the pure created animals God had originally created that were in that mandate, and which he chose to bring before Adam.

That seems (to me) to be as far as we can go with this matter. However, if size of animals is reckoned to be significant, a case for that would first have to be made. Size does not arise in the Genesis creation account.

Answer (score 1):

I believe until the flood came all animals were not meat eaters, neither were humans. In Gods kingdom it will go back that way. All animals will eat vegetation.( Isaiah 11:7) Isaiah 11 a description of what things will be like in Gods kingdon on earth.